# djangocms text_ckeditor wordcount plugin

Tags: ckeditor, django-cms, word-count, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I am working in a djangocms project that uses the djangocms_text_ckeditor https://github.com/divio/djangocms-text-ckeditor

I would like to integrate a wordcount plugin similar to this https://github.com/w8tcha/CKEditor-wordcount-Plugin

Have someone of you did this before successfully? It would be great if I could get the plugin via pip or so, not downloading and including it in the project. And also, how would the CKEDITOR_SETTINGS look like?

I couldn't find any workaround, just a similar post but that does not use this djangocms text editor for that purpose.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The extension is a javascript plugin for the ckeditor (as opposed to a djangocms plugin).

To load a javascript plugin two steps are needed:

1. Make the js plugin resources available to ckeditor. This is done through `static` folder in your project wich includes all js, css etc. files. In the `static` folder create the folders `djangocms_text_ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins`. Copy the js plugin into this folder. In your case thats the whole folder `wordcount`. The directory tree should look like

   ```
   static
   |
   +---djangocms_text_ckeditor
   |   |
   |   +---ckeditor
   |   |   |
   |   |   +---plugins
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   +---wordcount
   |   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   +---css
   |   |   |   |   +---lang
   |   |   |   |   +---plugin.js
   ```
2. Let the djangocms plugin ckeditor know about the js plugin. To this end, look for the setting `CKEDITOR_SETTINGS` in your project's `settings.py` file. If it is not there create it. It's a dictionary that is used, e.g., to configure the toolbars. In this dictionary have a key `extraPlugins` with a string value that consists of comma separated names of plugins to load, e.g.,

   ```
   CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {
       ...,
       'extraPlugins':  'cmsplugins,wordcount,glyphicons,...',
       ...,
   }
   ```

Hope that works for you.